# How can i get all the objects from the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been searching for this and i didn't find the answer for that.

I'm using Json encode to pass my array to JavaScript:

PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
$event_day = $row['event_day'];
$event_name = $row['event_name'];

   $data[] = array('event_day' => $event_day,
    'event_name' => $event_name
    );

}

echo json_encode($data, true);
```

JavaScript

```
 $.ajax( {
        type: 'get',

        url: "modules/groups/new.php",
         data : { 'list_day' : getday, 'month' : getmonth, 'year' : getyear, 'action' : 'selection'},
         success: function( response ) {

         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

         $('.' + getmonth).text(obj.event_name[0]); //calling the object here

        }

    });
```

The problem is that i just can get a specific object position, i have to do that:
obj.object[0], obj.object[1].

And i want to list all the objects from the array together.

I'm getting this:

```
[{"event_day":"9","event_name":"teste1"},{"event_day":"9","event_name":"teste2"},{"event_day":"9","event_name":"teste3"}]
```

And i want to print this:

```
Teste1
Teste2
Teste3
```

But i'm only getting the first object because i'm doing that obj[0].object

I heard about $.each, how can i implement that?

Thanks

Comment: You don't know how to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Back to the basics then: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Comment: I did a for loop, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines...

```
$.each(obj, function(index, data) {
    alert(data.event_name);
});
```

Then of course, replace the alert with whatever you want to do with the data...

Answer (score 0):

Non-jQuery dependent version...

```
for(var key in data) {
    console.log(key+"="+data[key]);
}
```